# de Casteljau algorithm Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw, curve

I'm not very mathematically inclined, so it would be great if someone could provide me a code example of de Casteljau algorithm in Objective-C. I'm attempting to calculate the points along a curve between a start point and an end point. Basically what I'm trying to do is create view that looks similar to a UIActivityIndicatorView. I would just use images, but it needs to be dynamic and have any number of ticks. My plan was to draw the view in four quadrants, top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. I was basically just going to draw one quadrant and then just create that view 3 more times and apply transforms to them to complete the circle.

[image]

I would appreciate any help, thanks!